# Multi Tab Reports and No Data

Tags: reporting-services

[No Data - Next Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhwvj.jpg)
[Render Error When Tab Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK5W1.jpg)

SQL Server: 2008
Report Builder 3.0

A multi-tab (8 tabs) report was created.  Each tab displays summarized data by specific types based on a date range. All of the data sets utilize the same stored procedure and the various results are based on the parameters passed. There appears to be two issues I have encountered.

1.) When  there are some empty data sets returned, the "NoRowsMessage" does not appear to be functioning correctly.  It works on the first empty data set it encounters, but if the user clicks on another tab that has an empty data set, the report throws a rendering error; even though the next table has the "NoRowsMessage" set.

2.) The second issue is that if the data set is empty and a message is displayed, The tab control for that section along with the message and the tab control / result table for the next section appear together.

Attempted Solutions:
1.) I set the NoRowMessage property with an IIF(First(Fields!LabID.Value,"DataSet Name") IS NOTHING,"No Data Found","") - Did not work
2.) I set the Hidden field for each table with an IIF(First(Fields!LabID.Value,"DataSet Name") IS NOTHING, True,False).  I then had a hidden text box with the No Data Found message appear. - Works but the tab controls for other tabs appear along with their data

The expected out put would be that when a tab is selected that it will display with the data shown or the No data found message.  The other tabs would not show until selected.

The actual results are as I described earlier.

Comment: How about you append all your datasets with a union of some sort to return one blank line.. and then check in the front end if there is only one line and that the value is blank.. then show a custom message that there is nothing to show? I know  the builtin function is "supposed" to work.. but that is why we have workarounds!

Comment: Thank you for your input and suggestion.  Unfortunately, each tab has its own data set.  The workaround I have in #2 above works because it does ascertain if the first record is blank, but I am trying to figure out how to hide the next tab and data table if a blank one is selected.